# Setting up a Read Replica for Reporting on Localhost with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

I'm looking to create a read replica of my PostgreSQL database on my localhost machine for reporting purposes.
This will help improve the performance of reporting queries and offload read operations from the primary database.

I have already installed PostgreSQL on my localhost and set up my primary database.
Now, I'm looking for guidance on how to set up a read replica on the same localhost machine to serve as a reporting database.

Some key considerations include:

1. Configuration settings for the read replica, such as `postgresql.conf`.
2. Replication method (e.g., streaming replication).
3. How to ensure the read replica stays synchronized with the primary.
4. Any specific considerations or optimizations for a local setup.

If anyone has experience or insights on how to achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance and any sample configurations that might be useful.

Thank you!

I tried to create logical Replication but failed .
I performed these steps:

wal_level = logical

CREATE PUBLICATION "PrimaryDBPub" FOR ALL TABLES
WITH (publish = 'insert, update, delete, truncate');

SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('Replicationslot', 'pgoutput');

CREATE SUBSCRIPTION CflSub
CONNECTION 'dbname=PrimaryDB user=db_replication_user password=spts@3311 host=localhost port=5432'
PUBLICATION PrimaryDBPub
WITH (slot_name = 'Replicationslot',create_slot = false);

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You certainly don't want logical replication, but streaming replication. But then, how should that improve performance if primary and standby database are running on the same machine?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You're correct that typically the most significant performance improvements from streaming replication are realized when the primary and standby databases are on separate machines.
However, in my specific situation, I am constrained by limited resources.My objective is to establish a read-only database for reporting purposes,
primarily aimed at alleviating the strain of read queries on the primary database.

Comment: The strain will still be on the machine (CPU, disk), so you are not going to gain anything.

Comment: More steps are required.. you can follow one of the tutorials, one is here -->  https://kinsta.com/blog/postgresql-replication/